# DOES A TIMEOUT OR GENERAL FAILURE COUNT AS A “HOP?”

Tags: command-line, traceroute

Im Working on a homework assignment asking to run traceroutes on major websites and fake websites. If it times out or fails does that count as a hop? The assignment wants me to notate number of "hops."

I am very Green to this subject look forward to the day that I will laugh at myself for asking this question

CO

tried running tracert espn.net expected no hops but 5 occured then 6 that timed out